# How to do PUT with netty 4.0 based client?

Tags: http, netty

I'd like to send a PUT request using netty, but get a timeout from the server. It seems as if the body is not sent. This is my code:

```
// open file to PUT
RandomAccessFile file = new RandomAccessFile("myFile", "r");
long fileLength = file.length();

// create request (without content, i.e. no DefaultFullHttpRequest)
HttpRequest request = new DefaultHttpRequest(HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1, HttpMethod.PUT, path);
HttpHeaders headers = request.headers();
headers.set(HttpHeaders.Names.HOST, host);
headers.set(HttpHeaders.Names.CONTENT_LENGTH, fileLength);

// send request
ch.write(request);

// send body - is this correct?
ch.write(new DefaultFileRegion(file.getChannel(), 0, fileLength), ch.newProgressivePromise());
ch.writeAndFlush(LastHttpContent.EMPTY_LAST_CONTENT);

// wait
ch.closeFuture().sync();
```

If this works Expect: 100-continue should be used of course.
Thanks for any hints.

Comment: Seems like it works with ch.writeAndFlush(new HttpChunkedInput(new ChunkedFile(file, 0, fileLength, 8192)), ch.newProgressivePromise()); even if my request is not chunked. A ChunkedWriteHandler has to be in the pipeline after the HttpClientCodec. ChunkedFile works with RandomAccessFile but I would prefer FileChannel, so I have to implement a ChunkedFileChannel since I don't know how to make use of DefaultFileRegion.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `DefaultFullHttpRequest` instead of `DefaultHttpRequest`

Doing that, you can use the method `DefaultFullHttpRequest.content()` to get a `ByteBuf` representing the content of the request. Just write your data into it before sending the request by calling `ch.writeAndFlush( request )`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I'm searching for a solution that uses a file reference and not a memory buffer so that very large files can be uploaded